# Create entry in SAPUI5 odata model offline

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm currently building a sapui5 app with odata. This app has to work offline, however everytime I try to set up a new entity with createEntry, the entry is not created until I run odataModel.submitchanges which performs a PUT request.

How are entries supposed to be correctly created in a offline scenario?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but you should be able to write a json model and use it as odata request. Like this

```
var mydata = {
            "milk": [{
                "Store Name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                "Revenue": 321421,
                "Cost": 200,
                "Consumption": 2321.4
            },
              {
                  "Store Name": "AAAAAAAa",
                  "Revenue": 4550208.3173505,
                  "Cost": 100,
                  "Consumption": 493776.33
              }]
        }
        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        oModel.setData(myData);
```

after that you should be able to use this model.

Comment: So the solution would be to use a json model until I am online again, and then attach it in the odata model?